# How to get onmouseover and onmouseout to work not as an inline function

Tags: javascript, html

How to get mouseOver and mouseout to work without calling them within the elements `<div onmouseover="mouseOver()" >`

```js
document.getElementById('smallBox').addEventListener("onmouseover", function() {
  document.getElementById('smallBox').style.color = "blue;"
});



document.getElementById('smallBox').addEventListener("onmouseout", function() {
  document.getElementById('smallBox').style.color = "yellow;"
});
```

```css
#smallBox {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="smallBox">hi</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Is it working? If not, do you get errors? If so, what errors?

Comment: I don't get any errors in console logs too. When I move the mouse or outside the box, the colors don't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names of the events are actually `mouseover` and `mouseout`. Another thing I had to change was the color attribute, which should just be `"blue"` instead of `"blue;"`

```js
document.getElementById('smallBox').addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  document.getElementById('smallBox').style.color = "blue";
});


document.getElementById('smallBox').addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  document.getElementById('smallBox').style.color = "yellow";
});
```

```css
#smallBox {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="smallBox">hi</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add event handler for that element in JS under onload function. `document.getElementById("smallbox").addEventListener("mouseover", myFunction)`

U need to call this function when the DOM is loaded.
     `document.getElementById("smallbox").addEventListener("load", functionName)`

Nd for event reference, visit [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)